# Проблема при делении проекта на отдельные файлы с классами

Tags: c++, ооп, файлы, классы, наследование

Такая проблема, код работает если все в одном файле **main.cpp**. Но если вынести класс в другой файл вылезает эксэпшин:

```
30: error: expected class-name before '{' token
 class STUDENT : public PERSON{
                              ^
C:\Users\CLionProjects\Pz_2_3\STUDENT.h:10:10: error: 'void STUDENT::Live()' marked 'override', but does not override
     void Live() override;
          ^~~~
C:\Users\CLionProjects\Pz_2_3\main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
C:\Users\CLionProjects\Pz_2_3\main.cpp:28:24: error: no matching function for call to 'PEOPLE::do_(STUDENT*)'
     people.do_(&student);
                        ^
C:\Users\CLionProjects\Pz_2_3\main.cpp:12:10: note: candidate: 'void PEOPLE::do_(PERSON*)'
     void do_(PERSON *pl){
          ^~~
C:\Users\CLionProjects\Pz_2_3\main.cpp:12:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'STUDENT*' to 'PERSON*'
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\Pz_2_3.dir\build.make:82: CMakeFiles/Pz_2_3.dir/main.cpp.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:95: CMakeFiles/Pz_2_3.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:102: CMakeFiles/Pz_2_3.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:137: Pz_2_3] Error 2
```

*Файлы:*

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>                 
#include "STUDENT.h"                
using namespace std;                
                                    
class PERSON{                       
public:                             
    virtual void Live() = 0;        
};                                  
                                    
class PEOPLE{                       
public:                             
    void do_(PERSON *pl){           
        pl->Live();                 
    }                               
};                                  
                                    
class DOCENT : public PERSON{       
    void Live() override{           
        cout << "\nDOCENT live";    
    }                               
};                                  
                                    
int main(){                         
    STUDENT student;                
                                    
    PEOPLE people;                  
                                    
    people.do_(&student);           
                                    
    return 0;                       
}
```

**STUDENT.h:**

```
#ifndef PZ_2_3_STUDENT_H
#define PZ_2_3_STUDENT_H


class STUDENT : public PERSON{
    void Live() override;
};


#endif
```

**STUDENT.cpp:**

```
#include "STUDENT.h"

void STUDENT::Live() {
    cout << "\nSTUDENT live";
}
```

*Заранее спасибо!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А как вы хотите сначала объявлять наследника `PERSON`, а потом сам `PERSON`?!

И второе - как вы хотите в student.cpp работать со `STUDENT`, если ничего не известно о `PERSON`?

По-хорошему, вынесите

```
class PERSON{                       
public:                             
    virtual void Live() = 0;        
};
```

тоже в заголовочный файл, до объявления `STUDENT`...